# OpenCV code interpretation

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to understand how Lucas Kanade openCV implementation works. Going through the code, these three types of declaration turn up very often:

```
#ifdef HAVE_TEGRA_OPTIMIZATION
    if (tegra::useTegra() && tegra::calcSharrDeriv(src, dst))
        return;
#endif

#if CV_SSE2
        for( ; x <= colsn - 8; x += 8 )
        {
            __m128i s0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(_mm_loadl_epi64((const __m128i*)(srow0 + x)), z);
            __m128i s1 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(_mm_loadl_epi64((const __m128i*)(srow1 + x)), z);
            __m128i s2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(_mm_loadl_epi64((const __m128i*)(srow2 + x)), z);
            __m128i t0 = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_mullo_epi16(_mm_add_epi16(s0, s2), c3), _mm_mullo_epi16(s1, c10));
            __m128i t1 = _mm_sub_epi16(s2, s0);
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(trow0 + x), t0);
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(trow1 + x), t1);
        }
#endif

#if CV_NEON
        for( ; x <= colsn - 8; x += 8)
        {
            uint8x8_t d0 = vld1_u8((const uint8_t*)&srow0[x]);
            uint8x8_t d1 = vld1_u8((const uint8_t*)&srow1[x]);
            uint8x8_t d2 = vld1_u8((const uint8_t*)&srow2[x]);
            uint16x8_t q4 = vaddl_u8(d0, d2);
            uint16x8_t q11 = vsubl_u8(d2, d0);
            uint16x8_t q5 = vmulq_u16(q4, q8);
            uint16x8_t q6 = vmull_u8(d1, d18);
            uint16x8_t q10 = vaddq_u16(q6, q5);
            vst1q_u16((uint16_t*)&trow0[x], q10);
            vst1q_u16((uint16_t*)&trow1[x], q11);

        }
#endif
```

I assume they are a part of code optimisation but could anyone explain what they stand for and how to interpret them?

Thank you.

Comment: OpenCV has optimisations for different CPU architectures and CPU instruction sets (so ARM NEON, tegra, SSE, etc). If you're just trying to understand the code it's usually best to ignore them and look at the implementation that isn't specialised.

Comment: as @y300 said, NEON is an optimization set for ARM processors, TEGRA is an nvdidia graphics chip on mobile devices, SSE are instructions of standard CPUs (typically applying same instruction for multiple data elements at once)